# Chicken breast out of oven after cooking a while; can I return it to the oven to continue cooking?

Tags: food-safety, chicken-breast

I cooked boneless chicken breast at 350 F (175 C) for 30 min, then took it out of the oven. I left it out for 30 mins or so; the temperature was 104. Can I return it to the oven to cook to a temperature of 165 now?

Comment: Was that the temp when you took it out of the oven or after it sat for 30 min? You might not need to cook it more if that was the temp after sitting for so long.

Comment: @Kat I highly doubt that a chicken breast will go from a safe internal temp to 104F in 30 min.

Answer (score 1):

In safety terms, yes. It's been in the 'danger zone' for a short enough time.

For texture, I'd say 30 mins was already borderline over-cooked, so it's only going to toughen up still further.

Comment: I agree, in principle, but tough to make a recommendation on this given the wording.  Remember, time in the danger zone is cumulative.  This assumes the chicken was never in the danger zone before cooking. It would be helpful to have more information.